# zsh: bus error with git on SMB volume

Tags: macos, smb, zsh, git

I regularly work with `git` on an SMB mounted share on my MacBook.  Recently I get this error every time I try to run certain git commands: `zsh: bus error  git status`.  The same error happens with log, diff, and show.  But other commands like `git remote` work fine.

From my searches online, this error suggests the memory address is not accessible.  I don't have any problems running git on a local folder.  And I haven't noticed any other problems with this SMB mount; I can read/write files.  The problem only happens with git on SMB.

I tried switching to bash and it has the same issue:

```
bash-3.2$ git status -v
Bus error: 10
```

I believe the repo itself is okay because I can run git commands via SSH on the remote server with no issue.

I believe this problem started when I upgraded to Ventura.  I'm currently on 13.2.1 with git version `2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)`

Comment: On what Mac hardware are you running this?

Comment: 2019 Macbook Pro

Comment: @Elliott did you ever figure out how to solve it? I'm having the same error (also with git on a SMB valume)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I don't know to fix that crap.

Comment: Does the error also occur with a git command which does not need to access the volume? For instance `git --help` or `git --version`. Does `git status` work on a repo which is not on SMB, for instance on your hard disk?

Comment: Yes, those commands (help and version) work fine, and `git status` works fine on the local disk.

Comment: Looks like a bug in this `git` version then. Is it an option to upgrade `git`? I'm using git 2.40.0 (installed via homebrew). If the error still persists, consider opening an issue (see [here](https://git-scm.com/community)).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error, and it seemed to be linked to using Git through Xcode's Command Line Tools. To resolve the issue, I decided to install Git separately via Homebrew.

Here's what I did:

```bash
brew install git
```

After running this command, I closed and restarted my terminal, which successfully resolved the issue.

The version of Git that was causing the error was `git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)`, but after installing Git through Homebrew, I was upgraded to `git version 2.41.0`.

So, if you're running into a similar issue, try installing Git via Homebrew and make sure to restart your terminal afterwards.

Moreover, if this doesn't solve the issue, as a temporary workaround, you can also try unmounting and remounting the SMB server. However, bear in mind that this might only provide a temporary relief as the issue may recur. If the issue persists even after using the above method, give this workaround a shot.

**UPDATE:**

I encountered this issue again. This time around, I tried a different approach: deleting the repository's .git directory and reinitializing it with git init. Strangely enough, this seemed to work, but I must confess, I'm still at a loss as to why this error occurs in the first place.

Comment: I think this "fix" was actually a coincidence.  I tried using git 2.41 from homebrew and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a git repository on SMB (using git version 2.42.0 from Homebrew). Unmounting the SMB share and mounting it again seems to have fixed it.